# Springfox Swagger2 with Spring MVC - 404 Errors

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, swagger

I'm attempting to integrate Springfox Swagger2 into an existing Spring 4 MVC application and running into issues with rendering some of the pages.

The following pages return 404 errors:

- `https://localhost:9002/swagger-ui.html`
- Anything under webjars

The following pages work fine and return JSON:

- `https://localhost:9002/swagger-resources/configuration/security`
- `https://localhost:9002/swagger-resources/configuration/ui`
- `https://localhost:9002/v2/api-docs`

I've added the following to my MVC configuration:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

Going to `https://localhost:9002/swagger-ui.html` shows a 404 error:

```
[15/Dec/2017:16:36:07 -0500] "GET /swagger-ui.html HTTP/1.1" 404 36691 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.91 Safari/537.36"
```

Going to `https://localhost:9002/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/springfox.js` shows the same:

```
[15/Dec/2017:15:10:08 -0500] "GET /webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/springfox.js HTTP/1.1" 404 36691 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.91 Safari/537.36"
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>storefront</display-name>

    <!--
     We have to explicitly clear the welcome file list.
     We don't need to serve a default or index page as we can handle all the requests via spring MVC.
    -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file/>
    </welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <description>
    Spring Expression Language Support
    </description>
    <param-name>
    springJspExpressionSupport
    </param-name>
    <param-value>
    false
    </param-value>
</context-param>

    <!-- filters -->
<filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
        <!-- set the amount of seconds the conf file will be checked for reload
        can be a valid integer (0 denotes check every time,
        -1 denotes no reload check, default -1) -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>confReloadCheckInterval</param-name>
            <param-value>600</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>



    <filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <description>
            ResourceFilter
            Filter used to server file resources by bypassing the other filters.
        </description>
        <filter-name>resourceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.company.storefront.servlets.ResourceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>resourceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ui/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/_public/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <description>
            SSLTerminationFilter
            Allows for SSL termination at the loadbalancer/HTTP server level
        </description>
        <filter-name>SSLTerminationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.acquitygroup.security.SSLTerminationFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SSLTerminationFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
    </filter-mapping>


    <!--  Begin custom security filters --> 

    <!--  Commented out for fixing log out issue

    <filter>
        <description>
            SecureSessionFilter
            Helps prevent session hi-jacking/fixation vulnerabilities
        </description>
        <filter-name>SecureSessionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.acquitygroup.security.SecureSessionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SecureSessionFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
     -->
    <filter>
       <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter</filter-class>
       <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
       <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
       <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <description>
            Spring configured based chain of the spring configurable filter beans
        </description>
        <filter-name>storefrontFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>storefrontFilterChain</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <description>
            OpenRedirectInterruptFilter
            Helps prevent against Open Redirect vulnerabilities
        </description>
        <filter-name>OpenRedirectInterruptFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.acquitygroup.security.OpenRedirectInterruptFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>OpenRedirectInterruptFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!--  End custom security filters -->   

    <!-- spring based filter chain -->


    <filter>
        <description>
            SpringSecurityFilterChain
            Supports delegating to a chain of spring configured filters. The filter name
            must match the bean name.
        </description>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>



    <!--  punchout filter for IE 8 -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>P3PFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.company.core.filter.P3PServletFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>P3PFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 


    <!-- HTTP Session Listeners -->
    <listener>
        <description>
            The HybrisContextLoaderListener extends the usual SpringContextLoaderListener (which loads
            the context from specified location) by adding the global application context of
            the platform as parent context. With having the global context set as parent you can access
            or override beans of the global context and get the 'tenant' scope.
        </description>
        <listener-class>de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <description>
            The RequestContextListener exposes the 'request' scope to the context.
            Furthermore it is needed when overriding the 'jalosession' bean for your web application.
        </description>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <description>
            The RequestContextListener exposes the 'request' scope to the context.
            Furthermore it is needed when overriding the 'jalosession' bean for your web application.
        </description>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- config -->
      <context-param>
        <description>
            The 'contextConfigLocation' param specifies where your configuration files are located.
            The 'WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml' file includes several other XML config
            files to build up the configuration for the application.
        </description>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param> 

    <!-- Servlets -->

    <!-- To Avoid server start up issues due to scope tenant  -->

       <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>      
         <init-param>    
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>de.hybris.platform.spring.ctx.TenantIgnoreXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>

         <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> 
   <!--   <servlet>
        <description>
            DispatcherServlet
            Spring MVC dispatcher servlet. This is the entry point for the Spring MVC application.
        </description>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>
                Specifies the location for Spring MVC to load an additional XML configuration file.
                Because hybris is already configured with the XML spring configuration files to load
                we must set this param value to EMPTY in order to prevent loading of the default
                /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml file.
            </description>

            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> -->

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet -->
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Uncomment in to enable handling of 500 server errors  -->
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/pages/error/serverError.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/pages/error/serverError.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <!-- handle csrf token errors due to session timeout! -->   
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>com.acquitygroup.security.csrf.RequestConfirmationTokenException</exception-type>
        <location>/login?timeout=true</location>
   </error-page>



    <!-- Session -->

    <session-config>
        <!-- Session timeout of 30 minutes -->
        <session-timeout>240</session-timeout>
    </session-config>


    <!-- JSP Configuration -->

    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <!-- Disable JSP scriptlets and expressions -->
            <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
            <!-- Remove additional whitespace due to JSP directives -->
            <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>

</web-app>
```

Just looking for some guidance on why this is occurring and how to resolve it.

Comment: Please paste your full url path. something like `http://localhost:port/your_app_context/swagger-ui.html`. Along with your servlet xml.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna added

Comment: Did you use maven ? If true then paste your `pom.xml`. If false, then mention which jar you include in the project for **swagger-ui**. Also not to forget to include which swagger config you used so far.

Comment: This comment might help you https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2151#issuecomment-354342704

Answer (score 0):

Please check the aop version, it should be the same version that is 4x. Please refer [Integrating Swagger with Spring 3.0.6.RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669609/integrating-swagger-with-spring-3-0-6-release) and https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/938. These are the frequent errors in using swagger.